# Bootstrap input group addon not same heigth

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I create a timpicker with input group addon.

```
<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                        <input id="timepickermailingtoupsummary" type="text"
                            style=" position: relative;"> <span
                            class="input-group-addon"><i
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                    </div>
```

But it returns

[image]

Can you I get same height.

Comment: what is your doctype ?

Answer (score 0):

You just forget to pply bootstrap class `form-control` to the input field. Just add the class as:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
    <input id="timepickermailingtoupsummary" type="text"  class="form-control" style=" position: relative;" /> 
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
    </span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Shaz4584/en6px1y4/embedded/result/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class `form-control` to your input:

```
<input id="timepickermailingtoupsummary" type="text" class="form-control">
```

And there are 3 class sizes as well.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="well well-sm">Default</h2>

  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
    <input id="timepickermailingtoupsummary" type="text" class="form-control"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>

  </div>
  <hr>
  <h2 class="well well-sm">Small</h2>

  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker input-group-sm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>

  </div>
  <hr>
  <h2 class="well well-sm">Large</h2>

  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker input-group-lg">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you..

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qW2wL/142/

```
    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker-component">
 <input type="text" class="timepicker-value input-small" value="12:42 PM">
 <span class="add-on">
    <i class="icon-time"></i>
 </span>
 </div>
```